# How to add elements to an array maanged by a smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

How do I access elements of a an array that is managed by a smart pointer?

I am getting an error

> struct has no member xadj

I provided some code below.

I've documentation on smart pointers here 
https://www.internalpointers.com/post/beginner-s-look-smart-pointers-modern-c

```
struct GraphStructure
{
std::unique_ptr<idx_t[]>  xadj;

GraphStructure() {

    //xadj = new idx_t[5];
    std::unique_ptr<idx_t[]>  xadj(new idx_t[5]);

}   

void function(GraphStructure& Graph) {
int adjncyIndex = 0;
int xadjIndex = 0;
Graph.xadj[xadjIndex] = adjncyIndex;
}
```

Comment: The code as is won't compile... Please have a look at [ask] and especially [mcve], which is what we need to be able to help you...

Comment: Take a step back from smart pointers and understand [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) first.

Comment: Appropriate code formatting improves code readability tremdously...

Comment: It is unclear why you want to manage this array yourself. `std::array` or `std::vector` _will_ be able to do what you need/want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a misnomer about how variables work in c++. In your example, you have 2 different objects of different types named `xadj` where one shadows the other:

```
struct GraphStructure {
idx_t* xadj; // A class member object named xadj of type idx_t*                    
GraphStructure() {


    std::unique_ptr<idx_t[]>  xadj(new idx_t[5]);  // A function scope object called xadj 
                                                   // that shadows the one above
} // At the end of this scope the xadj unique pointer is destroyed

...
void function(GraphStructure& Graph) {
    Graph.xadj[xadjIndex] = adjncyIndex; // Here you use the idx_t* xadj which cannot be 
                                         // accessed with operator[], only by derefencing 
                                         // (with ->). Even if you did use this accessor,
                                         // it would be undefined behaviour because xadj is
                                         // not initialized.
```

What you are probably looking for is something like this:

```
struct GraphStructure {
    std::unique_ptr<idx_t[]> xadj;     
    GraphStructure() : xadj(new idx_t[5]) {}
};
```

Comment: is it possible to initalise it in the body of the constructor and not in the initialization list?

Comment: @blacksheep If you want, but you should initialize in the initializer list where you can.